# RelativeLayout having FrameLayout with 15 ImageButton in it Crashes

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-framelayout

i have a activity with RelativeLayout in which there is a FrameLayout and in FrameLayout there are 15 ImageButtons. App crashes whenever that activity loads. here is my xml code.

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/bodyFrontView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bodyFrontBtn"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
            <ImageButton
               android:id="@+id/head"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="@null"
               android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
               android:scaleType="centerInside"
               android:layout_gravity="center"
               android:src="@drawable/head"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"/>
... so on 14
    </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

i havent even use anything in my java file yet. but still it crashes as soon activity loads.

here is my logcat actually some of it

```
09-28 18:25:12.487 5391-5391/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.proximatesolutions.daralhajama, PID: 5391
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(189422496bytes) bitmap.
        at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:229)
        at android.view.RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(RecordingCanvas.java:97)
        at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:529)
        at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1367)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20352)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19297)
```

100 more lines like this

Comment: whats the error you get? please post it to your question ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove   `android:background="@null"` from all `ImageButton`

Problem is your images are too large in terms of resolution or size. 
Now you can do two things:

1. Load image of low resolution(matching with height or width of image button) and small in size
2. Use Glide library to load images to `ImageButton`, It will change resolution according to view in which you want to display image.

Add this in build.gradle (app level) inside dependencies block

```
 compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

sync you project.

then in you activity on create :

```
 Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.bg).into(imageButton);
```

Use option 2 it will work definitely.

Comment: did that but still same

Comment: Problem with images ,  remove src from all image button property once and check

Comment: it worked if a remove src so how can i asign images?

Comment: sorry i am new can you tell me how can i use Glide library??

Comment: I have edited my answer, please check. Feel free to ask me, if you stuck anywhere

Comment: Most Welcome @WaqasArshad

Answer (score 0):

You need to resize your images to fit in memory or you can use below method to set images efficiently without resizing.

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap